# How to permit parameter from file field upload Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a csv import function in the application where I'm using the rails FormTagHelper `file_field_form`.

```
<h1>Offer import</h1>
  <div class="column left">
    <div class="widget">
      <h2>Select file</h2>
      <div class="bg-white pa3">
        <%= form_tag({ action: :do_import }, multipart: true) do %>
          <%= file_field_tag :csv_file, accept: 'text/csv' %>
          <%= submit_tag 'Process' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The method on the controller is using `params[:csv_file]` like so...

```
    def do_import
      file = params[:csv_file]

      if file.present? && file.content_type == "text/csv"
        importer = OfferImportWorker.new
        filename = importer.offer_csv(params[:csv_file])
        OfferImportWorker.perform_async(filename, current_user.email, current_user.id, file.original_filename)
        flash.now[:alert] = "Importing offers, an email will be sent when finished."
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Please select a CSV file"
      end
      render "import"
    end
```

When I try to upload the csv I'm seeing this error in the console `Unpermitted parameters: :csv_file`. Is there a way to permit this param? I know usually you permit params that exist on the model but this one doesn't.

Comment: Did you try `params.permit(:csv_file)` before calling it? 

Comment: @brcebn Yeah I get a `NoMethodError undefined method` error.

Comment: Weird. What's the class of `params` ? You're in a controller right?

Answer (score 0):

`Unpermitted parameters` just [raise when you explicitly declare what parameters be accepted and the input param is not one of them](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/UnpermittedParameters.html). So you should check on your controller (include it's supers) there is any `before_action` that `params.permit` be triggered, then if it's existed you can either skip that action for only method `do_import` or just add `:csv_file` to the list of permitted parameters (if it may not be cause error on creating model).